# How to detect if a section is suppressed in Crystal Reports v 11?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a **CRv11** report with two Group #1 footers (a & b) showing different information in each.

I have written some simple formulae controlling a shared variable to determine which footer displays: if the report is at its summary level (all suppress - drill down ok sections are hidden) I want it to show Group #1 footer a and if certain sections have been drilled into I want to show Group #1 footer b.

I've put a formula in the Report Header which sets the shared variable as 1 - this shows Group #1 footer a, and if I set the shared variable to 2 then Group #1 footer b is shown. So that part is working.

I believed (wrongly) that if I put a formula setting the variable to 2 in the hidden sections they would only be evaulated when the section was drilled into. Unfortunately this does not seem to be the case :(

What I need is a **IsSectionSuppressed()** function of some kind.
Can anyone with experience of this please shed some light?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check which drill down level you're viewing with the variable DrillDownGroupLevel. If the report is not drilled down at all (your summary only view), it'll be 0, if there is only one group present and is drilled down on, it will be 1, etc.

So it sounds like you want the following in section GF1a's suppression formula: `DrillDownGroupLevel<>0` and in section GF1b's: `DrillDownGroupLevel=0`

Comment: Thanks Ryan, a great help. Works brilliantly. John